# Can roots of any polynomial be expressed using Eulerian function?

Tags: galois-theory, polynomials, algebraic-equations

I encountered an interesting function which is called "Eulerian" by the Wolfram's MathWorld:

$$\phi(q)=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} (1-q^{k})$$

It is interesting because it is claimed that roots of any polynomial can be expressed in this function and elementary functions. Is this true and how the roots of arbitrary polynomial can be expressed?

P.S. In *Mathematica* this function is inplemented as QPochhammer[q]

Comment: Could you please link to where this statement is made? 

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This Euler function is essentially the same as Dedekind's eta function ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_eta_function), [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DedekindEtaFunction.html)). The usual use of the $\eta$ function is to express various modular forms. In particular, you should be able to rewrite [Hermite's solution of the quintic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical#The_Hermite.E2.80.93Kronecker.E2.80.93Brioschi_characterization) by modular functions in terms of the $\eta$ function.

I don't know whether you can express roots of higher degree polynomials in terms of $\eta$, but I would guess not. Here are my two hazy arguments:

- Hilbert conjectured that the roots of a general sextic could not be expressed using functions of one variable. I am told that this conjecture appears in *Über die Gleichung neunten Grades*, Mathematische Annalen Volume 97, Number 1, 243-250; I have not read this article. Abhyankar proves a version of Hilbert's conjecture in [this paper](http://www.nsc.ru/EMIS/journals/SC/1997/2/pdf/smf_sem-cong_2_1-11.pdf), which I discussed in my answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/61409/using-higher-order-bring-radicals-to-solve-arbitrary-polynomials/61558#61558). Unfortunately, to my limited understanding of Abhyankar's result, it is about *algebraic* functions of one variable, so it is not clear to me that it answers your question.
- According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical#The_Hermite.E2.80.93Kronecker.E2.80.93Brioschi_characterization), Hermite's solution of the quintic by modular forms was finally generalized to equations of arbitrary degree by Umemura, using Siegel modular forms. Siegel modular forms are analytic functions of many variables. This suggests to me that a generalization using modular forms in a single variable was found unworkable.

As you can tell by the hesitant style of this answer, I find the results on solving equations by transcendental functions rather hard to follow; they all seem to be written in very equation heavy nineteenth century style. Since these questions come up fairly often on MO, it would be great if someone could recommend a good survey which translates them into the modern language.

Comment: So basically, the answer should be 'yes' for degree 5 or less and 'no' for higher degree?

Comment: Should be. But there are a lot of caveats in the above. I'm hoping someone will give a clear reference to clean this all up.

Comment: Looks right.  The $\eta$ function gives access to classical modular functions, which give field extensions with Galois group contained in a quotient of some $\text{GL}_2({\bf Z}/N{\bf Z})$.  That's enough to deal with the generic quintic, but not sextics and beyond (though the sextics only barely fail: $A_6$ *is* of $\text{GL}_2$ type, but over the field of $9$ elements!).

Comment: In his appendix to Mumford's Tata II (using google books), Umemura writes, "Jordan [(Traité des substitutions et des équations algébriques)] showed that we can solve any algebraic equation of higher degree by modular functions. Jordan's idea is clarified by Thomae's formula[.] In this appendix, we show how we can deduce from Thomae's formula the resolution of algebraic equations by a Siegel modular function which is explicitly expressed by theta constants." I can't find what Jordan actually says in "Traité", though.

Comment: I guess what happens for Siegel modular functions is that the roots of any polynomial $P(x)$ generate the $2$-torsion field of the Jacobian of the hyperelliptic curve $C: y^2=P(x)$, so once you can compute modular functions for abelian varieties of genus $g(C)$ you can factor $P$.

Comment: @Noam There is a point that is confusing me in the other direction. $S_6$ is generatable by two elements, so there is a surjection $\Gamma(2) \to S_6$. So there is some function $\phi$ on the upper half plane, invariant for a finite index non-congruence subgroup, which generates an $S_6$ extension of $\mathbb{C}(j)$. Why can't I use $\phi(j^{-1}(z))$ to solve an arbitrary sextic?

Comment: @D.Speyer: because the kernel is not a congruence subgroup.

Comment: In his Traité p. 378, Jordan proves the following theorem : The solution of the general equation of degree > 5 cannot be reduced to that of equations arising from circular or elliptic functions. As far as I can see the proof boils down to show that the alternating group $\mathcal{A}_n$ with $n \geq 6$ is not isomorphic to $\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z})$ for any prime $p$. After that, Jordan also remarks that any equation can be solved by bisecting periods of hyperelliptic functions, as Noam said above.

Comment: Thank you, François and Noam for clarifying this for me.