# Any way around Abel's impossibility theorem?

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, solvable-groups

[Abel's impossibility theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem) states that the roots of a general polynomial (of degree 5 or higher) cannot be written using arithmetic operations and radicals. Radicals are solutions of a specific polynomial basis and it's natural to wonder if roots of an arbitrary polynomial can be written in terms of the roots of a different polynomial basis.

Let $p_1, p_2, \ldots$ be a basis for the space of polynomials, where $p_i$ is of degree $i$. A "generalized radical" is a solution to $p_i = \alpha$ for some $i$ and constant $\alpha$. For example, when $p_i = x^i$, we get the standard notion of radicals.

It is then natural to think of another polynomial basis, such as [falling factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) or some polynomial basis consisting of orthogonal polynomials. Is there a polynomial basis under which the generalized notion of radicals is powerful enough to express the roots of arbitrary polynomials?

A related problem is whether there is a richer (but nontrivial) set of algebraic numbers than usual radicals that can capture the roots of arbitrary polynomials.

Is there anything in the literature related to these problems?

Comment: There is a paper of Abhyankar which I believe shows that the answer is "no". See my answer at https://mathoverflow.net/a/61558/297 .

Comment: What does "A 'generalized radical' is a solution to $p_i = \alpha$" mean?  Does it mean that we are allowed to insert a symbol $\sigma_{i, \alpha}$ anywhere in an equation, and the equation is judged to be correct if some choice, for each such symbol, of a solution $\sigma$ of $p_i(\sigma) = \alpha$ makes it so?  (I mean to say, is a generalised radical a specific element of the field, or a place-holder that can stand for any one of potentially many such elements?)

Comment: Yes, you can use any root of any equation p_i = alpha for any i and alpha.

Comment: Quintics are solvable if you allow solutions of $x^5+x+a$ (but that's in addition to radicals, not in place of them).

Comment: Perhaps this [Q&A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3302437/is-there-an-analytic-way-of-solving-univariate-polynomial-equations-in-general/3302795#3302795) on the Math.SE could give some insight on what happens when the degree $n$ is $>4$.